# Weird glitches in Inkscape rulers

Tags: inkscape

I have a weird glitch when working with Inkscape. The little arrows in the rulers that show current cursor position remain there, not being erased. So I end with the ruler full of them, or just with a thick black line. This, obviously, renders this feature useless, as I can't tell the real position of the cursor. Here goes an example:

[image: Imagen]

Is there any way to fix this? Is it a video card driver problem or is it an Inkscape bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/627134). Apparently it's fixed in version 0.48.1.

Comment: That easy? That's the problem of using askubuntu all time... I didn't search anything else... Thank you. The problem is Maverick repositories have 0.48.0... Don't know if there's an official stable realease PPA (didn't find it in launchpad)... so I'll have to wait.